# How does USDC ever lose its peg?

Tags: stablecoins, usdc

If USDC is always backed by $1 worth of fiat or treasuries, how does USDC lose and then rebalance its peg on an ongoing basis?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because USD/USDC trade involves other matters besides collateral

- Withdrawal fees
- Transfer fees
- Inelastic supply and demand for USDC